# Overwriting Pandas dataframe is NA, based on multiple columns

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe

```
Name      Colour      1     2     3
Fred       Blue     dfd   dkd   dflkd 
Fred       Red      NaN    NaN   NaN
George     Green    sd    dked   flkd
James      Green    dg    sdfj   dfd
Alan       Green    fgf   sls    dkdk
```

I want to say if all columns 1, 2 and 3 are NaN, then replace with values in another dataframe, where the Name and Colour match.

Replacement dataframe

```
Name      Colour      1     2     3
Fred       Blue     3434   232    565
Fred       Red      122    5454  4545
```

So the output is

```
Name      Colour      1     2     3
Fred       Blue     dfd   dkd   dflkd 
Fred       Red      122   5454   4545
George     Green    sd    dked   flkd
James      Green    dg    sdfj   dfd
Alan       Green    fgf   sls    dkdk
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) and replace by matching both columns converted to `MultiIndex`:

```
df = (df1.set_index(['Name','Colour'])
         .combine_first(df2.set_index(['Name','Colour']))
         .reset_index())
print (df)
     Name Colour    1     2      3
0    Alan  Green  fgf   sls   dkdk
1    Fred   Blue  dfd   dkd  dflkd
2    Fred    Red  122  5454   4545
3  George  Green   sd  dked   flkd
4   James  Green   dg  sdfj    dfd
```

If possible duplicates in `df2` by first 2 columns:

```
df = (df1.set_index(['Name','Colour'])
         .combine_first(df2.drop_duplicates(['Name','Colour']).set_index(['Name','Colour']))
         .reset_index())
print (df)
     Name Colour    1     2      3
0    Alan  Green  fgf   sls   dkdk
1    Fred   Blue  dfd   dkd  dflkd
2    Fred    Red  122  5454   4545
3  George  Green   sd  dked   flkd
4   James  Green   dg  sdfj    dfd
```

Comment: Great thanks alot. its this definitely just overwritting rows that are NA? :)